# Django User update using model form with initial keyword

Tags: html, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to update the user profile using the model form by passing the already stored user details with the initial keyword. I don't know what is wrong in my code. When i click the submit button it just reloading the same page instead of updating/saving the details. Please i need some help to fix this issue.

```
## views.py ##

        def personal_details_update(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
        else:
            user = request.user
            data = {
                'username': user.username,
                'email': user.email,
                'first_name': user.first_name,
                'last_name': user.last_name,
                'address': user.address,
                'city': user.city,
                'state': user.state,
                'country': user.country,
                'mobile': user.mobile,
            }
            form = PersonalDetailsForm(request.POST or None, initial=data)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                if form.is_valid():
                    user.username = request.POST['username']
                    user.email = request.POST['email']
                    user.first_name = request.POST['first_name']
                    user.last_name = request.POST['last_name']
                    user.address = request.POST['address']
                    user.city = request.POST['city']
                    user.state = request.POST['state']
                    user.country = request.POST['country']
                    user.mobile = request.POST['mobile']

                    user.save()
                    return HttpResponseRedirect('/personal_details/')
                    # return HttpResponseRedirect('%s' % (reverse('personal_details')))
            context = {
                'form': form,
            }
            return render(request, 'login/personal_details_update.html', context)


        def personal_details(request):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/login/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login/personal_details.html')



## urls.py ##

        from django.conf.urls import url
        from . import views

        app_name = 'login'

        urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^$', views.home, name='home'),
        url(r'^about us/$', views.about_us, name='about_us'),
        url(r'^services/$', views.services, name='services'),
        url(r'^registration/$', views.registration, name='registration'),
        url(r'^login/$', views.login_user, name='login'),
        url(r'^admin/$', views.admin_login, name='admin_login'),
        url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
        url(r'^personal_details/$', views.personal_details, name='personal_details'),
        url(r'^personal_details/update/$', views.personal_details_update, name='personal_details_update'),
        ]



## forms.py ##

            from django import forms
            from .models import User
            from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget


        class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
            date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget)
            password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
            confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

            class Meta:
                model = User
                fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'date_of_birth', 'address', 'city', 'state',
                          'country', 'mobile', 'avatar', 'password', 'confirm_password']


        class PersonalDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
            date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=AdminDateWidget)

            class Meta:
                model = User
                fields = ['username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'address', 'city', 'state',
                          'country', 'mobile']
                exclude = ['date_of_birth', 'avatar', 'password', 'confirm_password']




## personal_details.html ##

        {% extends 'upload/base.html' %}
        {% block title %}Cloud | Personal Details{% endblock %}
        {% block folders_active %}active{% endblock %}
        {% load staticfiles %}
        {% block navigation%}
        <div class="container-fluid files-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="background: transparent">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="page-header">
                                {% if msg %}
                                    <p><strong><font color="#dc143c">{{ msg }}</font></strong></p>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <h4>Personal Details &nbsp;<a href="{% url 'login:personal_details_update' %}" class="btn-success" style="background: transparent"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></h4><br>
                            </div>
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_username">
                                        Username:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ user.username }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_email">
                                        Email:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ user.email }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_first_name">
                                        First Name:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ user.first_name }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_last_name">
                                        Last Name:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ user.last_name }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_date_of_birth">
                                        Date Of Birth:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ user.date_of_birth }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_address">
                                        Address:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ user.address }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_city">
                                        City:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ user.city }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_state">
                                        State:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ user.state }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_country">
                                        Country:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ user.country }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_mobile">
                                        Mobile:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ user.mobile }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_avatar">
                                        Avatar:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ user.avatar }}
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}



## personal_details_update.html ##

        {% extends 'upload/base.html' %}
        {% block title %}Cloud | Personal Details Update{% endblock %}
        {% block folders_active %}active{% endblock %}
        {% load staticfiles %}
        {% block navigation%}
        <div class="container-fluid files-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default" style="background: transparent">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="page-header">
                                {% if msg %}
                                    <p><strong><font color="#dc143c">{{ msg }}</font></strong></p>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <h4>Personal Details Update Form</h4><br>
                            </div>
                            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                                {% csrf_token %}

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_username">
                                        Username:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ form.username }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_email">
                                        Email:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ form.email }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_first_name">
                                        First Name:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ form.first_name }}
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_last_name">
                                        Last Name:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ form.last_name }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_address">
                                        Address:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ form.address }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_city">
                                        City:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ form.city }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_state">
                                        State:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ form.state }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_country">
                                        Country:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ form.country }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="control-label" for="id_mobile">
                                        Mobile:
                                    </label>
                                    {{ form.mobile }}
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class="col-sm-offset-5">
                                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Update</button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}
```

[This is the error message i'm getting when i try to update my personal_details form. Please someone help me fix it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJLP5.jpg)

Comment: Don't forget to show form errors in your template : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually I think your form is not valid, so the view reload the same page, but you don't display errors.

Comment: Thanks @Wilfried, i have uploaded the image that what error i'm getting when i try to update. Even if i remove the email field for update (hence email field is the unique field in my project) i got "this field is required" error, but im filling all the required fields. I think it's trying to create a new user instead of updating. Can anyone help how to update? Please check that

Comment: Sorry guys i found the mistake that was in the views.py,                                      form = PersonalDetailsForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user, initial=data)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                if form.is_valid():
                    user.save()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think error is, where you assign the "user" variable.

```
user = request.user
```

Instead of this you need to do this ,

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
```

In the case of latter, you are referring to the user object, on which you can update or change the data.

While in the former case, django is trying to create a new user which already exists in the database.That's why it gives the error you got. You just have to grab the one from the database and do manipulation on it.

I'm too a novice in django, hope you got what you where looking for.